# openCV from window to ios

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I want to train openCV from a server and send the xml generated by openCV to an ios device where an app will recognize the face using the xml trainned by the server. I will use openCV in both app but the server has window (trainning) and the device has ios (recognition).

So my main question is very simple:

The xml generated in openCV window version can be used an openCV IOS version without any trouble? Somebody made something similar who can give me some tips?

In window I will use .Net.

I think they won't have trouble because they are same libraries (openCV), so I suppose they have same internal algorithms but I want to be sure before start the project.

Best Regards and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, but you must train with images taken from your devices. It is normal to have multiple xml sets depending on your different cameras. Normally you release these with the binary, and not as a download but still...

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. As I said I need to create the xml in the server not in the device because the images are there and I won't download all images to the ios device to later train. That is why I need do the trainning in the server and later download to the device only the xml. You said that there is no problem. Are you sure? Did you read in any place or you know that because you did something like that?

Comment: I don't mean download all the images to your device. I mean now before you start the project, take some photos with the actual devices, upload them to the server or wherever you want actually, and run the training scripts. Then when you start your iOS project, you can just include the generated xml in the project as a resource file. You don't need a web server to update these xml files unless the camera can change - which isn't very likely on a mobile phone.